# Why can't I add CURDATE() into a check?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why can't I add CURDATE() into a check?

```
alter table TStudenten add constraint GebDatumCheck check (timestampdiff(YEAR, StudGebDatum, CURDATE()) >= 18);
```

What can I do that it works

When I want to add the CURDATE I get this Message

*Error Code: 3814. An expression of a check constraint 'GebDatumCheck' contains disallowed function: curdate.*

Comment: because a constraint doesn't just apply to when you insert or update, it's a condition that should remain true.  use triggers instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `CURDATE()` doesn't return a consistent result. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) says:

> Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of the connected user. Examples of functions that are nondeterministic and fail this definition: `CONNECTION_ID()`, `CURRENT_USER()`, `NOW()`.